Can't install Strapi with Next.js
I’m new to Strapi and this is my first time using it. I need to add its CMS to my Next.js application.
I’ve tried installing Strapi over and over again using npx create-strapi-app@latest but every single time I try I get the following error.

Node version - 20.16.0
npm 10.8
I’ve uninstalled and reinstalled Node and clear npm cache nothing worked.
Any Solution ?
